# What can iOS apps do in the background?

Tags: ios, background

Am I able to make my app process while in the background, or does it just sit dormant until it is brought to the foreground? Can I have it issue http requests, for instance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can figure out how to make your app fit within the bounds of "[App States and Multitasking](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html)" under the "Background Execution and Multitasking" section, then the answer is yes.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 7, you have 3 minutes for your App while it is in the background.
In older iOS, you should have 10 minutes for that.
You can see my answer with simple example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24197379/2407888).