# To conserve iPhone power, but allow data transfer over TCP-IP?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

To conserve iPhone power, but allow data transfer over TCP-IP what do I do?
I need to receive a constant stream of data all the time.   But I don't want to kill the battery in 4 hours by removing the sleep feature.

thx

Comment: it is very likely that the WiFi radio is draining the battery. You should re-think your data communication to use bursts. This allows the radios to sleep and conserve power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one word you cannot do that, you cannot transfer constant stream of data over TCP-IP. One user closes your app, apple restricts resource access to your app. This is apple way of conserving power. You need not worry about power.

I think this old question of mine would help you - [iOS Background downloads when the app is not active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8861390/ios-background-downloads-when-the-app-is-not-active)

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to reduce power a bit by sending or asking for data in the largest chunks possible consistant with smooth operation of your particular application, as larger data bursts may allow the radios to idle for longer periods between the data transfers; and allowing the wifi and cellular radios to turn off greatly reduces power consumption.