# How to keep downloading new images in background even if user force quits the app in iOS objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, download, background, afnetworking

I want to download many images around 300, and display it in the UI.

**I have two questions:**

1. If the app is in foreground, and suppose user sends it to background mode(by clicking on home button) then how do I assure the download to continue?
2. If the user force quits the app(doubleclick on home button and swipe the app from app switcher), then how do I ensure the app downloads the images?

I've been reading about background stuffs a lot. Few also say that in 2. case the download cannot continue.

**Below are the links I referred:**

http://www.appcoda.com/ios7-background-fetch-programming/
http://www.appcoda.com/background-transfer-service-ios7/
[iOS Background downloads when the app is not active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8861390/ios-background-downloads-when-the-app-is-not-active)

I'm not getting the right approach to download the images in foreground, background/suspended, user force quits the app. I'm using AFNetworking for webservice calls.

**Below is my code:**

I've image details like the URL in .json file uploaded to amazon. To download the file I do,

```
[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://someurl/imageFile.json"]];
```

From this file I read the urls of images and download them along with image details. This is a big process. How Do I handle it? Please help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution for your 1 question is below :**

> Background sessions let you perform uploads and downloads of content in the background while your app is not running. You can create a background session configuration by calling the backgroundSessionConfiguration: method on the NSURLSessionConfiguration class.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig;
float timeout = 5 * 60.0f;

BOOL iOS8OrNew = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0;
if (iOS8OrNew) {
    sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:identifier];
request.timeoutInterval = timeout;
}
else {
    sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfiguration:identifier];
sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForRequest = timeout;
}

sessionConfig.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 10;
AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:sessionConfig];

 NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request];


[manager setDidFinishEventsForBackgroundURLSessionBlock:^(NSURLSession * _Nonnull session) {
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if (appDelegate.backgroundSessionCompletionHandler) {
        void (^completionHandler)() = appDelegate.backgroundSessionCompletionHandler;
        appDelegate.backgroundSessionCompletionHandler = nil;
        completionHandler();
    }
    NSLog(@"All tasks are finished");
}];
```

**Add below code in your AppDelegate:**

```
 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:(NSString *)identifier
  completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler {
   self.backgroundSessionCompletionHandler = completionHandler;

   //add notification
   [self presentNotification];
}

-(void)presentNotification{
    UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification.alertBody = @"Download Complete!";
    localNotification.alertAction = @"Background Transfer Download!";

    //On sound
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

    //increase the badge number of application plus 1
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotification];
}
```

**For your 2 solution**

> If the system kills your app and your background session has active downloads, your downloads will continue and the system will launch your app when the downloads complete. However, if a user force quits your app, all tasks get cancelled.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I will try this.. But what about the second case? In iOS is i possible to download stuffs even if user quits the app from app switcher?

Comment: Ya.. I had read this in Apple doc.. But still even if the user quits the app, in android downloads do happen. I dont know why this feature is not there in iOS

Comment: Then should I download content when remote notifications are sent? Because If user quits the app, this delegate will always be called.. Is it the right way of doing?

Comment: @Medha If you setup a background NSURLSession task, the download is handled by the OS and not your app. Your app can terminate/crash whatever, but the download will not stop.

Comment: I tried the code and by browsing other sites regarding NSURLSession. It is working. But I have another question. If the app is in background say for 2 days.. If I want to download something after a day how should I do it? I mean how do I trigger the NSURLSession resume code again?

Comment: @Medha You have to go into the app background and resume it again.