# How to download files in background mode iOS? And Network connection Lost

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

In My App I download the audio files from the server, And the files are downloaded fine when the app is in foreground and when I clicked home button or lock button to force the app to go to background, then after some time, the download is stopped and the error comes as the `1005 network connection lost`. Whats the problem? Can Anybody explain the issue?

Code:

```
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:currentURL];
            NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url         cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData  timeoutInterval:60];
            receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:0];
            NSURLConnection * connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self     startImmediately:YES];
            myConnection = connection;            
            NSLog(@"%@ Download Started", currentURL);


- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    [receivedData setLength:0];
    expectedBytes = [response expectedContentLength];
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [receivedData appendData:data];
    float progressive = (float)[receivedData length] / (float)expectedBytes;
    [downloadProgressView setProgress:progressive];
    NSInteger val = progressive*100;
    downloadpercentageLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld%@",(long)val,@"%"];       
    //[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;       
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;   
}
```

Comment: are you check the background fetch in background mode?

Comment: This might be a duplicate. Have you checked out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8861390/ios-background-downloads-when-the-app-is-not-active ?

Comment: @MehmetEfeAkça I've tried several answers but didn't work out, And the accepted answer is not found. Please Help

Comment: @balkaransingh I don't know what is background fetch

Comment: Select your project -> capabilites  -> Backgorund modes -> backgorund Fetch

Comment: @balkaransingh Now checked it

Comment: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTaskId =[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bgTaskId];
        NSLog(@"%f",[UIApplication sharedApplication].backgroundTimeRemaining);
    }];
    NSLog(@"%f",[UIApplication sharedApplication].backgroundTimeRemaining);

Comment: add this code in applicationDidEnterBackground in app delegate and check.

Comment: @balkaransingh - Don't confuse background `NSURLSession` with background fetch. They're completely different things. He wants background `NSURLSession`, not background fetch. And the `UIBAckgroundTaskIdentifier` approach is only good for an extra 3 minutes, but doesn't handle network interruptions gracefully.

Comment: @Rob what is that network interruptions?

Comment: then @Rob What should we use for log running task in background more than 3 minutes? can you guide me.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/20808917/1271826

Comment: Please look at this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38195497/how-to-keep-downloading-new-images-in-background-even-if-user-force-quits-the-ap/38195715#38195715

Comment: How to download multiple files one after other

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use background `NSURLSession`. It handles network interruptions and downloads exceeding 3 minutes. See [Downloading Content in the Background](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW5) section of *The App Programming Guide for iOS*, which describes background downloads. Also refer to WWDC 2013 video in [What’s New in Foundation Networking](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/?id=705) (it's covered later in the video).

Comment: Thanks Rob, That works fine for single url download, If I give the second URL its not working its failed to download

Comment: It works fine for multiple downloads, too. Just make sure to use the same session object (or, worse, instantiate a new one with a new identifier).